# beeline equivalent of hive silent mode

Tags: hive, batch-processing, nohup, silent

I used to be able to use below hive command to run query file in batch mode and output the result to a CSV file. I used **-S** option to suppress the query log so only the query output is exported to the CSV file. I also used **nohup** to let the big job run even I logged out the system.

**nohup hive -S -f /home/wj19670/pad.sql >pad.csv &**

However under beeline, I can use the query in batch mode using below. But seems I can not use the **-S** option and **nohup** anymore. beeline is new to me. Does that beeline does not support -S and nohup?

**beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://server.domain.<>.com:10000/default;principal=hive/server.domain.com@SERVER.DOMAIN.COM' -f filename.hql**

Answer (score 1):

This is part of [Hive-6758](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6758).

If you are using a version that is not fixed, the following workaround will work,

`export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal" && beeline -f query.hql & disown`

I tested this with disown but not nohup, but the solution should be the same.